# HTML won't link to CSS in GitHub Repository

Tags: html, css, github

I am having a hard time getting my HTML to pull in the linked CSS sheet in GitHub. It works fine in test environment, but when I upload everything to my repository it doesn't link.

Snippits of my code are below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css/">
    <title >Megan Holmes</title>

</head>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might just be that you're using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css/">
```

Instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mystyle.css/">
```

in your file path.
See if that makes any difference

Comment: to be more clear, I'm referring to the back path
    ../

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly reference the file.

One method would be putting all css files in a `css` folder, which would make the html look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css/">`

Another would be to reference the css in the root folder, like you presumably have it set up, which would look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mystyle.css/">`

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that your files are called correctly

for example if they are in the same root folder :

root /

- index.html
- styles.css

  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css/">`

now if the css is in a different path and not the same as the index.html

root /

- index.html
- css/styles.css

  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css/">`